# create-react-app npm run build command

Tags: reactjs, build, npm, create-react-app

I have a built a small React application with **create-react-app**, and it runs fine from the local server after running `npm start`. OK so far.

However, when I run `npm run build`, the process appears to execute correctly (creates build folder, which contains the bundled js file and the index.html file), but when I open index.html in my browser it renders nothing. What am I missing?

---

**Aside:** I also tried uploading it to a remote server and when I went to the URL the browser came back with...

> Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on this server.

...if anyone has any idea how to resolve this I'd also appreciate it.

Comment: Do you see any js error in the browser console when loading the index page?

Comment: Use webpack. There are so many ways to create a react app. Webpack emits a bundle file which is invisible when we are running webpack server by `npm run start`. I can't understand that why you are building another file separately. In my case, I just created index.html file, index.js file and other js files. Used webpack to integrate.

Comment: @ Charan Cherry: I already am using webpack. create-react-app is a customised webpack configuration. The command line `npm run build` creates the index.html file, and the corresponding javascript is all bundled into one minified js file, all placed in a single folder, 'build'.

Answer (score 37):

> However, when I run npm run build, the process appears to execute correctly (creates build folder, which contains the bundled js file and the html.index file), but when I open index.html in my browser it renders nothing. What am I missing?

When you run `npm run build`, it prints the relevant instructions:

[image]

You can’t just open `index.html` because it is supposed to be **served with a static file server**.
This is because most React apps use client-side routing, and you can’t do that with `file://` URLs.

**In production**, you can use Nginx, Apache, Node (e.g. Express), or any other server to serve static assets. Just make sure that if you use client-side routing, you serve `index.html` for any unknown request, like `/*`, and not just for `/`.

**In development**, you can use `pushstate-server` for this. It works with client-side routing well. This is exactly what the printed instructions suggest you to do.

> I also tried uploading it to a remote server and when I went to the URL the browser came back with Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on this server.

You need to upload the contents of the `build` folder, not the `build` folder itself. Otherwise the server can’t find your `index.html` because it is inside `build/index.html`, and so it fails. If your server doesn’t detect a top-level `index.html`, please refer to your server’s documentation on configuring files served by default.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've heard about Heroku - https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration - I'm going to read up on it, but is this one way of deploying a live (not local) react application, on a remote server?

Comment: Yep. Alternatively you can copy the build folder to any remote server you have access to and configure any static server software to serve it.

Comment: Works for me!  Short answer: Trust the instructions that you see from `npm run build`.

Answer (score 7):

you can't run the production build by clicking on index.html, you have to modify your script like bellow.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "deploy": "serve -s build"
  }
```

after running npm run-script build, run npm run-script deploy, you will get some thing like this, this is where you can load your production build.

npm install -g serve before run npm run-script deploy.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

open index.html file.
scroll near end and you will see

```
<script src="/static/js/2.b5125f99.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.fcdfb32d.chunk.js"></script></body></html>
```

just add a dot in front of the two src attribute:

```
<script src="./static/js/2.b5125f99.chunk.js"></script><script src="./static/js/main.fcdfb32d.chunk.js"></script></body></html>
```

also if you have any styles you must also scroll near beginning where you will see:

```
<link href="/static/css/main.1eabf3ab.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and also place a dot in front of the href attribute

```
<link href="./static/css/main.1eabf3ab.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

NOTE: filename may/will not be the same for you

also be sure to change this back when using a server or just run npm run build again(i have no idea what happens if you dont)

Answer (score 4):

Here You can solve this problem in 2 possible ways.

1.Change the routing history to "hashHistory" instead of browserHistory in the place of

```
 <Router history={hashHistory} >
   <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
   <Route path="/aboutus" component={AboutUs} />
 </Router>
```

Now build the app using the command

```
sudo npm run build
```

Then place the build folder in your var/www/ folder, Now the application is working fine with addition of # tag in each and every url. like

localhost/#/home
   localhost/#/aboutus

Solution 2 : Without # tag using browserHistory,

Set your history = {browserHistory} in your Router,Now build it using sudo npm run build.

You need to create the "conf" file to solve the 404 not found page,
the conf file should be like this.

open your terminal type the below commands

cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
ls
nano sample.conf
Add the below content in it.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@0.0.0.0
    ServerName 0.0.0.0
    ServerAlias 0.0.0.0
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory "/var/www/html/">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now you need to enable the sample.conf file by using the following command

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo a2ensite sample.conf
```

then it will ask you to reload the apache server,using
     sudo service apache2 reload or restart

then open your localhost/build folder and add the .htaccess file with content of below.

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^.*$ / [L,QSA]
```

Now the app is working normally.

Note: change 0.0.0.0 ip to your local ip address.

I hope it is helpful to others.

Answer (score 3):

After building your application through `create-react-app` [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)

Run command `npm run build` After that run command `npm install -g serve` & finally `serve -s build`

More detailed information can be found from here [create-react-app-deployment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment)

Answer (score 3):

Just enter these two commands in your terminal:

```
npm run build

npx serve -s build
```

After this just go to localhost:5000

Answer (score 2):

'Web Server for Chrome' extension is super easy to use. Install it and set the directory to the ~/my-react-app/build/

Answer (score 2):

1. `cd` to your build folder,
2. `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` to start a server on port 8080,
3. go to address `localhost:8080/index.html` in your browser.

Comment: I tried the same. It works. But the route doesn't change. Any Idea why?

Comment: Super simple way to run a production build files in local system. Thanks

Comment: Another simple way is to run `serve -s build`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run the same command and react app was also showing white screen.
main js file was taking the relative path to the file and showing error when I open js file in new browser "Your file was not found"
I make it to absolute path and its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.taniarascia.com/getting-started-with-react/ and The final script can be found on the GitHub.

npm run build  -> will create a folder build which include the index.html and static folder. By just clicking the index.html will open on a new browser's tab. But it shows only blank page. Why? because it's need a server to make it works.

Solution :

Move the file on other folder. Open the folder using VC Code. Open the index.html and right click -> select : Open with live server. A new tabs opened on your browser with related ip address and port.

Or you can run it on localhost using xampp :

Open the XAMPP server. Place it on localhost. And it must work.