# react -npm run build makes an empty page

Tags: reactjs, npm, build, create-react-app

I have made a web app that has a few components and displays some texts depending on which button is pressed. However when i do npm run build it makes the build folder and everything in it but once i click on the index.html file it opens a blank page, same happens when i try to open it through a [link on github](https://wesely1996.github.io/myBookWebApp/). If anyone can help me figure this out i would be very thankful.

---

[-my web app picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNbwd.png)

[-successful build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aibis.png)

[-files in the build folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDbQV.png)

Comment: Run it on a web server.
See the build informations.
Run:
npm install -g serve
serve -s build

Comment: Are you using create-react-app ?

Comment: 1337 - i tried this but it didnt change anything
PS C:\Users\Nikola\Desktop\myBook\my_book_app> npm install -g serve serve -s build
C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Roaming\npm\serve -> C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serve\bin\serve.js
+ serve@10.1.1
+ serve@10.1.1
+ build@0.1.4
********
Crying Freeman - yes, i am

Comment: i followed all suggestions made in this thread but none of them worked => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791069/create-react-app-npm-run-build-command?rq=1

Comment: Is it your site served ok, if you make serve -s build ? Locally

Comment: this is what i get when i type run serve -s build:   Serving! Local:            http://localhost:5000  On Your Network:  http://X:5000

Comment: If it serves the app ok locally, then your problem is in the server(IIS or Apache or whatever) where your compiled app runs, the compiled SPAs created by create-react-app or angular-cli will run on any http server. If you do complex things with the react router then take a look at that

Comment: @Nicola have you tried to open your serving app with localhost:5000 in your browser?